# Firefox extension: detect that URL in address bar was changed explicitly by user

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

There's a way to get a notification of URL change in a Firefox window using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners#Example.3a_Notification_when_the_value_in_Address_Bar_changes

Unfortunately, this method is too much common. It informs when user navigates to another page either by clicking a link, or by using the back/forward button, or by typing an address in the location bar, etc.

Can I detect only those changes that were typed in the address bar explicitly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably handle the textentered event on gURLBar.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to override gURLBar method: `var old_handleCommand = gURLBar.handleCommand;
   gURLBar.handleCommand = function(event) {
    // XXX : do your magic
    old_handleCommand.call(gURLBar, event);
   };`